# i am trying to make a disney plus clone but i am having a error which says module not found

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, database, firebase

./src/app/store.js Module not found: Can't resolve '../features/movie/movieSlice' in 'C:\Users\user\diseny-plus-clone\src\app'

so please tell me how to rectify this problem

this is the code of the file having error

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "../features/counter/counterSlice";
import movieReducer from "../features/movie/movieSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movie: movieReducer,
  },
});
```

next is the code of the file through which i have imported

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  movies: [],
};

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setMovies: (state, action) => {
      state.movies = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setMovies } = movieSlice.actions;

export const selectMovies = (state) => state.movie.movies;

export default movieSlice.reducer();
```

please help me

Comment: Double check the module path is correct.

Comment: yes path is correct

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGE**

```
export default movieSlice.reducer();
```

**TO**

```
export const movieReducer = movieSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: error has not resolve,giving same error do u think it is because of older redux version

Comment: did you wrap your app with <Provider> ?  also do you have index.js file in your store folder ?